# Rails 3 my first nested form doesnt work - Can't mass-assign protected attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-forms

I'm creating my first nested form in `Rails 3.2.13`. `User` is registering and he fill `email`, `password` and `address` information and `company` information.. but the error is showing while user click on submit. Error is at the bottom.

Im not sure about this line: `attr_accessible :address_attributes, :company_attributes`
which i read it could help but it doesnt and i have addresses in the view but address in the model because of one-to-one relationship but if i have `<%= f.fields_for :**address** do |builder| %>` the form doesnt show up.
Please what i have to do ? :-)
The post sends then

```
"companies"=>{"name"=>"Companyname"
```

**User model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible ...

    has_many :orders
    belongs_to :address
    belongs_to :company

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :company
    attr_accessible :address_attributes, :company_attributes
```

**Company model**

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible ...
    has_many :users
    validates_presence_of ...
end
```

**Address model**

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible ...
    has_many :orders, :foreign_key => 'payment_address_id'
    has_many :orders, :foreign_key => 'delivery_address_id'
    has_many :users

    validates_presence_of ...

end
```

new.html.erb (creating new user)

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  ...

  <%= f.fields_for :addresses do |builder| %>
   ...
  <% end %> 

  <%= f.fields_for :companies do |builder| %>
   ...
  <% end %> 

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**error** while i click on submit

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: addresses, companies
```

**EDIT:**

**First mistake**: i changed in **Class User**

```
belongs_to :address
belongs_to :company
on
has_one :address
has_one :company
```

and in **Address and Company model** i edit

```
has_many :users
on
belongs_to :user
```

but nested forms doesnt show up in the view.. i tried edit Users Controller by adding .build method

```
 def new
   @user = User.new
   @user.company.build
   @user.address.build
 end
```

but im getting **new error**

```
undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass
```

please what i have to do now ?

Comment: user cant have companies or address as you have stated a belongs_to relation in your user model

Comment: sunny1304: ouch thats right ! thank you i will try fix it.

Comment: sunny1304: i edited my post now please look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a case like this a day ago, and that's what I used.

```
class User
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :company_attributes, :address_attributes
  has_one :company
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company
end
```

and EmailSetting:

```
class Company
  belongs_to :user
end
```

after this I can run in console:

```
User.new.build_company
```

as for form:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :company do |builder| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

in controller you just initialize the `@user` variable, no need to do `@user.company.build` or `@user.address.build`

Comment: Hi thank you for this, it works :-) but i had to add 
`@user.build_address
@user.build_company`
to user method for forms displaying.. now i have another problem.. if i fill the form it says me _state column in addresses cant be blank_, thats because i dont want to have multistate right now.. i add this to **AddressControler**
`def create
 if params[:address][:state] == nil then params[:address][:state] = "ab" end
...`
i can solve this by default value of course but im only curious whats wrong here, anyway you solve my problem thank you !

Comment: Can't say much here, as I don't see your code. The last guy I helped out I had to install his app on my computer to debug his issue. I would try first to check if you have any validations for address model, like validate presence of states, if you don't need states for now you can comment that validation. But again, I can't say much without more code. You better write another question with the related code in it and you might get a better reply how to fix it.